# Using NuGet for InsuranceBot sample comes back with error for .NetCore in VS 2017

Tags: .net-core, nuget, botframework

I'm trying some of the botframework samples and one such InsuranceBot requires install of Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis in Visual Studio 2017.

When I follow instructions:-
Right click on the InsuranceBot project and click Manage NuGet Packages.
Select the Browse tab and search for Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis.
Click on the NuGet package, select the latest version and click Install.
Add the LUIS Recognizer to your bot

Error I get is:-
The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.2.  Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.2

I looked up dotcore --version and it comes back with 2.2.
Alos, I see 2.1 and 2.2 version sdk under C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk

How can I get around this and target 2.1 sdk? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does installing a VS 2017 compatible version of the .NET 2.2 SDK help? E.g. 2.2.107 from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download?

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it still gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

The easiest instructions for me to write are: edit the csproj (if you're using Visual Studio, you can right click the project in Solution Explorer and select "Edit Project File") and change `netcoreapp2.2` to `netcorapp2.1`.

I don't have VS2017 on this machine, but possibly you could check the Visual Studio Installer, modify your installation and look for .NET Core 2.2 in the components list. I know it's there for VS2019, just not sure about VS2017. Otherwise you can do as Martin Ullrich suggested in the comment to your question and download the .NET Core 2.2 SDK, but as he said, you need to make sure you get one compatible with VS2017.

Finally, if your csproj has a `<TargetFramework>`, rather than a `<TargetFrameworks>` element, you should also be able to right click the project in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer, select properties and on the Application tab there's a dropdown for Target Framework. Generally this can be used to switch TFMs (target framework moniker) without manually editing the csproj, although I'm not sure if it works when the current TFM is not available on the machine.

Unless you're intentionally using .NET Core 2.1 because it's the LTS version, then I'd recommend installing the .NET Core 2.2 SDK.

Comment: Thanks, I changed version of <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework> to 2.1 and it gives different errors relating to AspNetCore which the proj has 2.2.3

Comment: You'll need to make sure that all of ASP.NET Core package references use 2.1 versions, not 2.2. I still suggest installing the .NET Core 2.2 SDK so you can use netcoreapp2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Installed Visual Studio 2019 along with Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis 4.3.2 with no errors. Install was successful. Hence, marking it as answer.

Thanks @Martin Ullrich and @zivkan for your input!